# What does superscript + mean in relational algebra?

Tags: relational-algebra, notation

What does superscript + mean in relational algebra?  Suppose $A$ is a subset of attributes of all attributes in a relation $R$.  What does $A^+$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.  $A^+$ represents the set of attributes that $A$ functionally determines.